# Broken submit form

Tags: jsp

Hi i'm trying to do a simple check if there's a session and if is not show another content on my form, but when i click submit button nothing happens.

```
<h1>Online banking</h1>
<% 
     String useremai =  (String)session.getAttribute("email");
    if(useremai!=null)
     {%> 

    Welcome Mr(s). <%=useremai%>                

<%

        }
     else 
     {
            %>
    <form action="index_activate.jsp" method="post" name="myform" id="myform" onSubmit="validateBlanks();return false;">
    E-mail  <input class="input" id="email" name="email" type="text" style="width:120px; text-align:center" value=""/><br><br>


    Password <input class="input" id="password" name="password" type="password" style="width:120px; text-align:center" value=""/><br>

    <div id="tip_login_otp" style="position:absolute; visibility:hidden; margin:-35px 0 0 -35px;">
    <img src="images/tip_login_otp.png" />
    </div>      
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="image" style="margin: 10px 0 0 20px; float:right" src="images/bt_submit.gif" />   

    <% 
    String email = request.getParameter( "email" );
    session.setAttribute( "email", email );

    String password = request.getParameter( "password" );
    session.setAttribute( "password", password);
    %>      

</form>
```

Comment: Nevermind my error was on onSubmit="validateBlanks();return false;"> function.